# Is there any performance gains or necessity in unbinding an element's events before deleting it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any performance gains or necessity in unbinding an element's event(s) before deleting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE6 and IE7, yes. http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html

Comment: It varies from browser to browser, but according to Crockford, Firefox and Opera have both overcome this issue. My guess is, anything created after 2005 doesn't have this bug. But, it is only a guess.

Comment: Testing in IE11 now and it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If the event was created with jQuery, and the element is being removed through jQuery as well, then you don't need to as all event handlers for that element and all of its child elements will also be deleted by jQuery before deleting the element.

see [`.remove()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L359), [`.empty()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L380), [`.html()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L407) and [`.cleanData()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L279).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. That's the advantage of making use of a library!

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of IE can't garbage collect circular references between the DOM nodes and JavaScript objects because DOM nodes are only collected via reference-counting. Therefore programmers must manually break these references to avoid leaking memory.

Functions bound as a property of an element (such as events) always have the `this` property that points back to the element so they form a guaranteed circular reference.